# Sorting Excel columns in numeric order

Tags: excel, sorting, columnsorting

I have several columns in Excel that looks like this:

[Excel columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEzBK.jpg)

Notice the column headers in the first row, 56g_flux_data39(1)1992, 56g_flux_data39(10)1992, 56g_flux_data39(11)1992, etc.

I want to sort them in numerical order, so 56g_flux_data39(1)1992, 56g_flux_data39(2)1992, 56g_flux_data39(3)1992, all the way to 56g_flux_data39(11)1992; but Excel's sorting function doesn't seem to recognize the numbers between the brackets (1).  It wants to group the numbers beginning with 1 together, for example (1), (10), (11).

How do I get Excel to see the (10) and (11) as a ten and eleven and sort them in proper numerical order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another row above your column title with the following formula. This will isolate the number, which can then be sorted according to its numerical value (tested, see screenshot below):

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A3;LEN(A3)-16);LEN(A3)-21)
```

[image]

Comment: Your formula doesn't seem to work for me.  I keep getting an error saying that there is something wrong with the formula.  

This is what I typed:  =LEFT(RIGHT(A3;LEN(A3)-16);LEN(A3)-21)

Comment: Please try to use commas instead of semicolons, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a zero in front of the single digits. Pad with more zeros if you have higher numbers.

56g_flux_data39(01)1992, 56g_flux_data39(02)1992, 56g_flux_data39(03)1992, all the way to 56g_flux_data39(11)1992